# How can I delete all the documents in an elasticsearch index that does not contain a specific value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that contain various fields like ( timestamp, metric_name, etc). 
I want to delete all the documents whose `metric_name` field **does not match** the value `cpu/time` or `query/time`.

Comment: take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: please share the mapping

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to `POST` below `_delete_by_query`:

```
POST <put_your_index_name_here>/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [{
        "terms": {
          "metric_name.keyword": ["cpu/time","query/time"]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Resources:

- [Delete By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-delete-by-query.html)
- [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
- [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-terms-query.html)
- [keyword sub-field](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Tried with another method(posted below).

Answer (score 2):

If the deleted records are more, don't miss  to run forcemerge for deleting them completely.
Delete by query just marks them as deleted rather than deleting them

Comment: Yes, figured it out when I could see the index size was still the same after deleting documents.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the following way as well.

POST /_delete_by_query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [{
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "metric": "cpu/time"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "metric": "query/time"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

**match_phrase** worked because didn't have the matching prefix in other metrics